# Parsing PDML in perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, wireshark, tshark

I need to develop a perl script that parses packets captured by Wireshark that were exported to PDML format, does some field value cross-referencing.

The main points of interest are being able to order packets by timestamp (frame.time_epoch),filter them by different combinations of field values and distinguishing fields inside GTP.

I've tried a couple of XML modules and XML::Simple seemed to come close to solving the timestamp problem with the keyattr option, but I couldn't make it work with nesting, to order ancestor nodes by attribute values of their descendants.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Looks promising. Is it available on Fedora through yum?